# Scala: Tokenizing simple arithmetic expressions

Tags: regex, scala, split, tokenize, calculation

How can I split `23+3*5` or `2 + 3*5` into a list `List("23", "+", "3", "*", "5")`?.

I tried things like `split`, `splitAt`, but nothing with the wished result.

I want that it splits at the arithmetic operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like

```
"2 + 4 - 3 * 5 / 7 / 3".split("(?=[+/*-])|(?<=[+/*-])").map(_.trim)
```

In this particular example, it gives you:

```
Array(2, +, 4, -, 3, *, 5, /, 7, /, 3)
```

The `(?= )` are lookaheads, `(?<= )` are lookbehinds. Essentially, it cuts the string before and after every operator. Note that `-` in `[+/*-]` is at the last position: otherwise it's interpreted as a character range (e.g. `[a-z]`).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest matching on what you want as tokens.
e.g.

```
"\\d+|[-+*/]".r.findAllIn(" 23 + 4 * 5 / 7").toList
// List(23, +, 4, *, 5, /, 7)
```